# How to pass bootstrap modal values to laravel controller using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have created a bootstrap modal with some input fields and I am trying to pass those input values to controller and need to insert into db.But it displays null.

It will be helpful if anyone solves my issue.

Comment: Ok, provide your model code with route too

Comment: Provide your html, js, controller code to

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727405/how-to-insert-modal-values-into-db-using-ajax-post-request

Comment: There includes all my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the JS code and laravel redirection with JSON format data like answered by [Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727405/how-to-insert-modal-values-into-db-using-ajax-post-request). Added here for other people help so credit goes to him.

**JS code:**

```
$("#priceSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'addPriceDetails/{{$dataId}}',
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.SKUID);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function addPriceDetails(Request $priceform,$dataId) {
    // ... all your code
    return response()->json([
        'SKUID'    => $priceInfo->SKUID,
        'listingStatus' => $priceInfo->listingStatus
        // ... any other fields you want to return
    ]);
```