# Submitted Information from a Modal Into mySQL

Tags: javascript, php

I was having some problems submitted information from a modal into mySQL, this is what I have tried.

```
<script>
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.table-row > td');
var cellIndex = -1;
    cells.forEach((e, index) => {
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //show modal
    $('.modal').modal("show");
        //update grid
    // This is the row number
    console.log("Row number: ", index)
    cellIndex = index
 })
})

function updateTable(e) {
let name, email, phonenumber, tableRow, row;
name = document.getElementById("name").value;
console.log(name, email, phonenumber);
// Get the row that you want
row = cells[cellIndex];
$(row).html(name);
$('.modal').modal("hide");
}

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", updateTable);


  //store in database
  $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),
    success:function(data)
    {
      alert('form was submitted');
    }
  })

</script>
```

This is my insert.php:

```
    <?php

    $conn = new 
    mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password");

     if($conn->connect_error){
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn- 
    >connect_error);
      }

     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
         $output = '';
         $name = 
 
 mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["name"]);
       $phonenumber = 
 
 mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["phonenumber"]);
      $email = 
 mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["email"]);


      $query = "INSERT INTO users(name,phonenumber,email) VALUES('$name',
                '$phonenumber','$email' )";

        

  }

  echo "Connected successfully";


?>
```

My understanding of the problem is that I need to use ajax to send a request to the web server that would store the information from the modal to the mySQL database with the given query in php. Perhaps I don't have a good understanding of the problem. I am not sure how to get the values from the modal, and in conjuction use ajax to send a post to the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Modal:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h1>Reservation</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

              <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Name" id="name">

              <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Email" id="email">

              <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="PhoneNumber" id="phonenumber">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

              <input id="submit-btn" name="submit" class="btn submit" value="Submit">
              <input class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert modal values into db using ajax post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727405/how-to-insert-modal-values-into-db-using-ajax-post-request)

Comment: The connection is stored in `$conn`, but later you're using `$connect`. You're also never actually running the insert query. Regarding AJAX, you can inspect the request in the browser's dev tools. Press F12 to bring them up and check the console tab.

Comment: @ChrisG How do I bind the ajax request to the button submit? When I load the page it automatically prints the alert from the ajax request.

Comment: The click handler function you assign is `updateTable`, so you could move your AJAX call in there for instance. I didn't even notice it's not inside a function because of your completely arbitrary indentation. I recommend fixing that, so your code it more readable.